# Edit JAXB generated annotation using annox and add namespace in param

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, jaxb2-basics, annox

I do have the following annotation in a JAXB generated class

```
@XmlType(name = "MessageInfoType", propOrder = {
    "debugTraceBoolean",
    "clientHostnameString",
    "endUserIPAddress"
})
```

Need to produce the following annotation in JAXB class with custom binding..i.e is need to edit the above annotation and add a namespace using annox as below type.

```
        @XmlType(name = "MessageInfoType", propOrder = {
            "debugTraceBoolean",
            "clientHostnameString",
            "endUserIPAddress"
        }, namespace="urn:expedia:e3:data:messagetypes:defn:v4")
```

my xjb file is:

```
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../serviceDescription/atlantis/common/com.expedia.e3.data.messagetypes.v4.xsd">

    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='MessageInfoType']">
        <annox:annotate target="field">
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType" 
                   namespace="urn:expedia:e3:data:messagetypes:defn:v4"/>
        </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: need to override an exisiting annotation in the JAXB generated class or either remove it with help of annox in the custom binding file.Please help me out

Answer (score 5):

Affiliation disclaimer: I am the author of the [Annotate Plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin).

If you try to add an annotation which already exists (same location, same annotation class), this will modify an existing annotation rather than add a second one. I am not sure at the moment, if this will override all the attributes or merge new ones, but it's definitely worth trying.

Update:

I've rechecked this. Indeed, it is implemented (should be of version 0.6.4, I've just checked with 0.6.5-SNAPSHOT).

Check this sample:

https://svn.java.net/svn/jaxb2-commons~svn/basics/trunk/tests/annotate/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb

Here's the binding:

```
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='issueJIIB39CType']/xs:attribute[@name='test']">
        <annox:annotate target="field">
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute" required="false"/>
        </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

If this binding is present, you'll get:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "test", required = false)
protected String test;
```

If not it will be like this:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "test", required = true)
protected String test;
```

So, as I said if you add an annotation at the very same place and the very same class, they will be merged.

Comment: I have installed JAXB2-basics-annotate 0.6.4, JAXB2-basics-ant 0.6.4,  JAXB2-basics-tools 0.6.4 and rest of them are
jaxb-api, jaxb-impl and jaxb-xjc jar(dont know what is the version of these jars). I am getting the below bold error  after using 0.6.4 version jar and guessing this is because of some version mismatch. I am using JDK 1.6.0.29 and does 0.6.4 goes only with JDK 1.7 please confirm?

Can you tell me what is the version of all other jars I need to use..because I am getting the below error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.codemodel.JAnnotatable.annotations()Ljava/util/Collection;

Comment: Hi lexicore - any idea why the links to the Annotate Plugin docs you pasted above is broken? Is this a temporary problem, or has the project been discontinued?

Comment: The server goes down time after time. Back online now.